# TicketMaster Dicsovery API - how to distinguish between events with different ticket options

Tags: ticketmaster

Many concerts have regular and VIP tickets (maybe more) and TicketMaster returns separate event data for each one.

I'm simply trying to select the 'main' event and ignore the rest.  I searched the documentation and can't find any flags to indicate which event is the default event.  There is a 'primary' flag under 'Classifications' but this value is true for all ticket types.

Anyone?